# Local parameter at infinity on a hyperelliptic curve and poles of differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-forms, elliptic-curves

I'm trying to understand some stuff regarding differentials on a hyperelliptic curveof genus $g$. I'm working with an odd model, $C: \;y^2=f(x)$ over $\mathbb{A}^2_F$, where $F$ is a characteristic $0$ field. I'm looking at the de Rham cohomology $H^1_{DR}(C)$. I get why the basis of this cohomology is given by

$$\omega_0 = \dfrac{dx}{y}, \omega_1= x\omega_0,\omega_2= x^2\omega_0,...,\omega_{2g-1}= x^{2g-1}\omega_0 $$

where if projective co-ordiantes are $[X:Y:Z]$ then $x = \dfrac{X}{Z}$, $y= \dfrac{Y}{Z}$. What I am trying to get my head around is the following:

At infinity, $x$ has a pole of order $2$ and $y$ has a pole of order $2g+1$. This then means that $\omega_0, \omega_1,...,\omega_{g-1}$ are all holomorphic at infinity, and can be extended to regular differentials on the complete hyperelliptic curve. However, $\omega_g,...,\omega_{2g-1}$ are not holomorphic and have in fact got poles of orders $-2,-4,..,-2g$ at infinity. Therefore, they do not extend to regular differentials at on the complete elliptic curve. I have been trying to understand this, but everywhere I go it seems like it is simply asserted.

I've tried to understand the corresponding statement for elliptic curves - i.e. that $\omega=\dfrac{dx}{y}$ and $xw$ are regular and of the second kind respectively, but again it doesn't seem clear to me. If we take, as suggested in other places, the local co-ordainte $t = \dfrac{x^{g}}{y}$ then it would come out pretty quickly, but really this to me is using what we want to show to show exactly that.

Needless to say, I'm a bit confused and would appreciate a nudge in the right direction. I guess it has something to do with the fact that we'd want to consider the class of the divisors $(\dfrac{X}{Z}),(\dfrac{Y}{Z})$ coming out of $K(C)$ and then consider the valuation $v_{\infty}$ at these classes, but I'm struggling a bit.

Comment: The space of holomorphic differentials on a genus $g$ curve has dimension $g$, right? Thus if $\omega_g,\ldots,\omega_{2g-1}$ are linearly independent from $\omega_0,\ldots,\omega_{g-1}$ it doesn't surprise me that they are not homolorphic! I guess they should be anti-holomorphic, or something like that...

Comment: I think what I'm trying to figure out is the following - why is it that $x$ has a pole of order 2 at infinity, and $y$ has a pole of order $2g+1$? It's easy enough to see for an elliptic curve, but any of the arguments used for elliptic curves are not working out quite right for me here. But I agree with you, that we would expect only $g $ to be holomorphic - I guess what I didn't make quite clear enough is that I want to understand the poles at infinity explicitly for each differential

Comment: Well that doesn't look too hard. To find the divisor of the rational function $x$, which is $x/z$ in projective coordinates, you just have to look at the zeroes of $x$ and the zeroes of $z$. Now $x=0$ intersects $C$ in 2 affine points $P,Q$ and the remaining $2g-1$ are just $(0:1:0)$ with multiplicity $2g-1$. On the other hand, $z=0$ is tangent to $C$ in $(0:1:0)$ with multiplicity $2g+1$. Thus, the divisor of $x$ is $P+Q-2(0:1:0)$, which shows that $x$ has a pole of order $2$ at infinity.

Comment: In the same way you can compute the divisor of $y$, you'll see that it is of the form $\sum_i P_i-(2g+1)(0:1:0)$, where the $P_i$'s are $2g+1$ points on the affine part of $C$.

Comment: How do we know that $X=0$ intersects C in two affine points? I get the idea is something like on the affine part, these points correspond to $y^2=f (0)$, but what if $F$ is not algebraically closed?

Comment: in fact they correspond to the solutions of the equation you quoted! keep in mind that divisors of rational functions are always computed on the algebraic closure of $F$, since otherwise it's not guaranteed that the divisor has degre 0.